# Spring bean scope : singleton and Prototype

Tags: spring

Case 1 : Suppose we are injecting singleton bean inside prototype bean then how many instances will be created if we call prototype bean.

Consider the scenario :-

```
<bean id="a" class="A" scope="prototype">
 <property name="b" ref="b">
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="B">
```

Case 2: Suppose we are injecting Prototype bean inside singleton bean then how many instances will be created if we call singleton bean.

Consider the scenario :-

```
<bean id="a" class="A" >
  <property name="b" ref="b">
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="B" scope="prototype">
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering a part of your question.

**Case2: Singleton beans with prototype-bean dependencies**

With this configuration, it is expected that when ever you fetch A from application context, it will be wired with a new B as we declared the B bean is of prototype scope. But this **will not happen**.

When the application context gets **initialized**, it sees that A is a singleton bean and initializes it to the context after wiring it with all the dependencies set. So from **then onwards** when we request context for A, it return the same bean every time, So you will also get the **same B** everytime.

You can solve/**overcome** this by using **Lookup method injection**. Refer this [article](https://prasanthnath.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/injecting-a-prototype-bean-into-a-singleton-bean/).

Answer (score 0):

The singleton bean will always refer to the same object. The prototype will have as many instances created as many times that bean is referenced. The use cases you provided don't change this paradigm.